# Elegant way to handle multiple DB operations by single method

Tags: java, jdbc

What is the most elegant way to handle different DB operations by single method? 
Let's say there's an interface:

```
public interface ServiceDAO {
    void addRecord(UserRecord userRecord);
    void delRecord(UserRecord userRecord);
    void updateRecord(UserRecord oldRrecord, UserRecord newRecord);
    List<UserRecord> getAllRecords();
}
```

It's implemented by some class which would also have method for connecting and executing statements on database. 
At this point I was wondering if there's any nice solution to have one universal method - something like

```
private Collection<UserRecord> executeStatement(<some args>)
```

which will be able to both process simple SQL selects and do updates? Then all other methods would simply call `executeStatement()` with appropriate arguments.
It would've been rather simple task by building SQL string with all parameters as plain text, but that's a bad approach and one should always stick with parametrized PreparedStatements.

I was thinking about creating an object with fields like

```
class SQLparameters {
    String SQL;
    ArrayList<UserRecord> records;
}
```

and passing it to `executeStatement()` but I expect unnecessary complications if logic becomes more sophisticated (i.e. few different possible UPDATE statements or SELECT with many parameters).

Are there any patterns to cover such scenario or should I simply put separate connection handling logic in every method of aforementioned interface?

Comment: This would violate the [Separation of Concerns principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Why would, for example, an insert or update necessarily return a `Collection`? I would rather expect it to return the inserted/updated object. Furthermore, JPA implementations like Hibernate can take care of implementing commonly used functionalities based on the method name.

Comment: In addition, how are you going to handle exceptions halfway through? You need a way to unwind the statements that succeeded prior to failure. If you are not going to use a cookie cutter ORM, you should think about Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pseudocode

```
private Collection<UserRecord> executeStatement(String ... args){
    String preparedStatementSql = args[0];
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
    dbConnection.prepareStatement(preparedStatementSql );
    for(int i=1;i<args.length;i++){
        preparedStatement.setObject(i,preparedStatementSql[i];
    }
    // if true, then it's select query
    if(preparedStatementSql.execute())
      return preparedStatementSql.getResultSet().convertToListOfUserRecrod();
    else
      return null;
}
```

Note that this is not a best practice at all, you shouldn't allow any query to be called dynamically, this will be a problem in terms of coherence, decoupling and code maintenance. Not to mention that it's hard to track the problem here, a lot of tools using methods to check performance issues that depends on method names(stacktraces), here for example you won't be able to find what's the exact query that caused a performance problem because a lot of them goes throw this method.

Nevertheless, JPA implementing vendors will merely requires you to write two lines of code to attain any query, especially with sophisticated query languages like HQL.

Answer (score 0):

That's where Spring Templates shine. Spring templates (`JdbcTemplate` in your case) removes boilerplate code, resource management, and exception translation. It just has the signature similar to what you need, with a lot more.

I suggest you to create a DAO class with a clear interface, and wrap all `JdbcTemplate` usage in it, and don't let SQL stuff (the queries and ...) leak to other parts of your code. So don't expose SQL and queries beyond the scope of DAO class.

By the way why do you want to do the update and select in a single method? It seems that you are violating `Single Responsibility Principle`.

Comment: The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is defined on class-level, not method level.

Comment: There are levels of this principle, method level, class level and even module level. According to Uncle Bob because of this principle even logging should be separated into different method from main code.